# Source control options for single dev to shared webhost

Tags: php, version-control, mercurial, lamp, shared-hosting

I work with Mercurial during my day job as a php developer, but I also run a forum on the side, for a hobby of mine.

I'm struggling to get much development work done on the forum as I just can't bring myself to edit files and manually upload them, it seems archaic, keeping crummy difficult to manage backups as I go.

I run a simple LAMP stack at home, and have all the usual tools to hand, but my webhost for the forum is a simple shared package which doesn't allow local source control clients running and I have no shell access.

What are my best options? I know source control can't be properly implemented, but;

I could have a local repository which I work in, and a separate (pseudo-remote, but actually local) repository in which I can push code to from my local repository when I'm happy with it, and have a hook trigger rsync to get changed files and upload them via ssh to the shared host, it seems as if this could function as a primitive source control setup for my situation.

Does this sound viable? Are there any other options?

Comment: If you can `ssh` to the shared host, then you should be able to `rsync` from your local machine. Set up a shell script that contains the right ignore files, and then just run to deploy. That said, if you can switch to a VPS, consider doing so - they are sooo cheap these days.

Comment: Johnny, the forum is free, no ads no revenue, it's a public service that I fund. I can't allocate more money to hosting.

Comment: Halter, thanks, so on the 2nd "pseudo remote" repo, I'd rsync that to the remote server then setup a hook in mercurial so when I've pushed code to that repo, it'll trigger rsync? Sounds workable, seeing that there's no other solutions available to me. :)